# Convert string binary to hexadecimal

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int digitNumber=1;
        int sum = 0;
        String binary = "1110101011111010";
        String hex;
        for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++)
        {
        if(digitNumber == 1)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*128;
        else if (digitNumber == 2)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*64;
        else if (digitNumber == 3)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*32;
        else if (digitNumber == 4)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*16;
        else if (digitNumber == 5)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*8;
        else if (digitNumber == 6)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*4;
        else if (digitNumber == 7)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*2;
        else if (digitNumber == 8)
        {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*1;
            hex = Integer.toString(sum,16);
            System.out.print(hex);
        }
        else if (digitNumber == 9)
        {
            digitNumber = 1;
            sum=0;
        }
        digitNumber++;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to convert String of Binary to Hexadecimal. My string binary is "1110101011111010". The output should be EAFA, but my output is EA7A.
What's wrong with my code? Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Why don't you use `Integer.parseInt(binary, 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you expect a long `string`, you can use `BigInteger` to convert any binary string to hexadecimal.

```
public static String convertBinaryToHexadecimal(String binaryStr) {
    return new BigInteger(binaryStr, 2).toString(16);
}
```

**Output:**

```
BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
String binaryStr = num.add(num).toString(2);                // 2 times bigger than long
System.out.println(convertBinaryToHexadecimal(binaryStr));  // fffffffffffffffe
```

---

```
public static String convertHexadecimalToBinary(String hexadecimalStr, int length) {
    return String.format("%0" + length + 'd', new BigInteger(new BigInteger(hexadecimalStr, 16).toString(2)));
}
```

**Output:**

```
String hexadecimalStr = "7B";
System.out.println(convertHexadecimalToBinary(hexadecimalStr, 8));  // 01111011
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert Hexadecimal to Binary by using the same method:
return new BigInteger(hexStr, 16).toString(2); 
When I input "5", it converted to "101" instead "0101". What should I do to get exactly 4 digits with 0 at front?

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too much code.

Try this:

```
String hex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(binary, 2)); // handles up to 63 bits
```

Remember: The more code you have, the more places there are for bugs to lurk.

Comment: Can I use it with a large number of digit binary? For instance, if my binary string have 32 digits. Can I split it to 4 parts, each part have 8 digit to convert?

Comment: I changed it to handle up to 63 bits

Comment: What if my binary string length over 63 bits? Actually, I need to do over 63 bits

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem in your code is that in the case of `digitNumber == 9`, you set `digitNumber` to 1 and then increment it, but you don't parse that digit, so you're skipping the first bit of the second byte you're parsing.

The recommended approach would be to switch to using `Integer.parseInt(binary, 2)`, `Long.parseLong(binary, 2)` or even `new BigInteger(binary, 2)`.

However, if you want to fix your code, you need to move the check for `digitNumber == 9` to the start of the loop, and independent of the other if-statements, so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
    if (digitNumber == 9) {
        digitNumber = 1;
        sum=0;
    }

    if(digitNumber == 1)
        sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i) + "")*128;
    else
    // rest of your if...
    digitNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly easiest to use the built-in functions like @Bohemian♦ has done. But if you really need/want to do the binary conversion manually, you can change your `for` loop to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(binary.length() - i - 1) + "") * (1 << i);
}
```

This loops through the binary string from right to left. `1 << i` is equivalent to `Math.pow(2, i)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used basic approach for convert string binary to hexadecimal, please find below:

```
public class StringToHexaDecmal {

    // Driver program to test above function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String num = new String("1110101011111010");
        int decValue = binaryToDecimal(num);
        stringToHexadecimal(decValue);
    }

    // Function to convert binary to decimal
    static int binaryToDecimal(String n) {
        String num = n;
        int dec_value = 0;

        // Initializing base value to 1,
        // i.e 2^0
        int base = 1;

        int len = num.length();
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (num.charAt(i) == '1')
                dec_value += base;
            base = base * 2;
        }

        return dec_value;
    }

    // Function to convert decimal value to Hexadecimal
    private static void stringToHexadecimal(int no) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String hexadecimalNo = "";
        char c;
        while (no != 0) {
            int rem = no % 16;
            if (rem > 9 && rem <= 15) {
                c = (char)(rem + 55);
                hexadecimalNo = c + hexadecimalNo;
            }
            if (rem < 10) {
                hexadecimalNo = rem + hexadecimalNo;
            }

            no = no / 16;

        }
        System.out.println(hexadecimalNo);
    }
}
```